# Avoiding multiple left joins of a single table for multiple columns

Tags: sql, postgresql, performance

Mock up table and data of the problem I'm facing:

```
create table table1 (people varchar(10), special_id varchar(20));
create table table2 (special_id varchar(20), dependent_value int8, value_wanted varchar(5));

insert into table1 values 
('person1', 'abc'),
('person1', 'abc'),
('person1', 'abc'),
('person1', 'abc'),
('person1', 'bbb'),
('person1', 'bbb'),
('person1', 'ccd');


insert into table2 values
('abc', '02', 'boom'),
('abc', '01', 'zoom'),
('bbb', '01', 'woom'),
('abc', '03', 'whom');
```

This is the result I'm trying to achieve:

```
+---------+------------+---------+---------+
| people  | special_id | code_01 | code_02 |
+---------+------------+---------+---------+
| person1 | abc        | zoom    | boom    |
| person1 | abc        | zoom    | boom    |
| person1 | abc        | zoom    | boom    |
| person1 | abc        | zoom    | boom    |
| person1 | bbb        | woom    | NULL    |
| person1 | bbb        | woom    | NULL    |
| person1 | ccd        | NULL    | NULL    |
+---------+------------+---------+---------+
```

Using the mock up table, I can create the table above by doing this:

```
select t1.*, t2.value_wanted as code_01, t2_1.value_wanted as code_02
from table1 t1
left join table2 t2
on t2.special_id = t1.special_id and t2.dependent_value = '01'
left join table2 t2_1
on t2_1.special_id = t1.special_id and t2_1.dependent_value = '02';
```

The problem is in order to add `code_03` and additional columns, I'll have to continually add left joins. This doesn't seem very efficient. Is there a better way to do this with performance in mind?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can also use aggregation:

```
select t1.*, t2.code_01, t2.code_02, t2.code_03
from table1 t1 left join table2
     (select t2.special_id,
             max(case when t2.dependent_value = '01' then t2.value_wanted end) as code_01,
             max(case when t2.dependent_value = '02' then t2.value_wanted end) as code_02,
             max(case when t2.dependent_value = '03' then t2.value_wanted end) as code_03
      from table2 t2
      group by t2.special_id
     ) t2
     on t2.special_id = t1.special_id ;
```

Instead of a new join, you need to add a new condition to the subquery.  Whether this is faster or slower . . . well that depends.

Comment: Thanks, this worked. Performance wise, doing `max(t2.value_wanted) FILTER (WHERE t2.dependent_value = '01') as code_01` gives the same result but results in slight performance improvement.

Comment: @Simon . . . I am guessing about 10-20% faster.